# Random variable with density of Joint Distribution Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Give two IIDRV X and Y over (0,1), 
Then their joint probability density be given by p(x,y).
Let f be a function of X and Y

Questions : 
1.) Does there exist a random variable U = f(X,Y) with probability density = p(x,y).

2.) Let W = XY
Can We write P(W<=z) = $
\int_0^1 P(Y<= \frac {z}{x} ) dx $

I logically know that answer to both questions is "no", but I am intutively not able to understand why so?

Comment: 1) If $U$ is an univariate random variable, then yes it is weird to associate it with a joint pdf with two arguments (i.e. the domain is different). But you need more info so that you can claim something meaningful rigorously. Suppose $X, Y$ are independent uniform random variables on $(0, 1)$ and $U = X$. Then what will be your claim? 2) What is $V$?

Comment: 1.) U can be a multivariate,
2.) Sorry I was working out with different notations, updated.

I am unable to understand what to you mean by "What will be your claim"?

Comment: 1) So if $f$ is the identity function such that $\mathbf{U} = (X, Y)$, then they have the same density (or even $\mathbf{U} = (Y, X)$ will do); 2) Yes you can write like this due to law of total probability, Why say no?